# How do you remove Favorites Shortcut (.cannedSearch) from Network Mount?

Tags: finder, shortcut, folders, server.app

I accidentally had the sidebar open and dragged the "All My Files" shortcut under Favorites into a server folder where client's folders are organized alphabetically. No one can seem to delete this file. The Finder says that it's still in use which I'm wondering if it means by my machine, or now that it's on the whole server if it's everyone's computer. The computers in the room are all iMacs running various version of Mac OS. It's showing up as a "Predefined Search". I attached a screenshot of what it looks like stuck inside the client main folder. Thanks!

[image]

Comment: When all the users are logged out of the server, and you've temporarily shut down file service, try deleting the file from the server itself.